# php calling function in string concatenation

Tags: php

I have problem to calling function in string concatenation

i have this function :

```
function  site_url() {
    include("../connect.php");
    $title= mysql_query("select * from shop_option where shop_key='site_url' ");
    $row_title= mysql_fetch_array($title);
    print ''.$row_title['shop_feild'].'';
}
```

This function will tell website url eg ( http://google.com )

and i want to call this function in string concatenation

```
echo '<script language="javascript">'.'window.location =
    "'.site_url().'";'.'</script>';
```

i also called function into variable ! to testing but it's not work

```
$page = site_url();
echo '<script language="javascript">'.'window.location = "'.$page.'";'.'</script>';
```

so how can i call function when i want to string concatenation ?

Comment: _"but it's not work"_ the `error_log` or inline error should give you a pretty good idea on what's wrong with your code

Comment: is that `$row_title['shop_feild']` or shouldn't that be `$row_title['shop_field']`

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the result of site_url rather than printing the text immediately.

```
function  site_url() {
    include("../connect.php");
    $title= mysql_query("select * from shop_option where shop_key='site_url' ");
    $row_title= mysql_fetch_array($title);
    return $row_title['shop_feild'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your function should not print but return the value:

```
function  site_url() {
    include("../connect.php");
    $title= mysql_query("select * from shop_option where shop_key='site_url' ");
    $row_title= mysql_fetch_array($title);
    return''.$row_title['shop_field'].'';
}
```

in order to pass it to the caller which then prints the returned value.

Comment: Those empty string concatenations are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of print, use return:

```
function  site_url() {
    include("../connect.php");
    $title= mysql_query("select * from shop_option where shop_key='site_url' ");
    $row_title= mysql_fetch_array($title);
    return $row_title['shop_field'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function site_url() does not return the selected value.

```
function  site_url() {
  include("../connect.php");
  $title= mysql_query("select * from shop_option where shop_key='site_url'");
  $row_title = mysql_fetch_array($title);
  return $row_title['shop_feild'];
}
```